# java regex failing for multiple group

Tags: java, regex

Below regex is working fine in most of the regex tools. However, its not working in the java code. Can anyone please advise?

```
String text="CHANGE FEE/ADD COLLECT DATA                                   "+
                "1.1  COLOR/RED TOMATO                                         "+
                "CF   USD10.00                                                 "+
                "                                                              "+
                "2.2  COLOR/DARK BLUE PLUM                                     "+
                "CF   USD11.00                                                 "+
                "                                                              ";
        String patterString = "([0-9]{1,3}\\.[0-9]{1,3})\\s.+\\s*CF\\s+[a-zA-Z]{1,5}([0-9]{1,10}.[0-9]{2})";
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(patterString);  
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);    

        while (matcher.find()) {    
            System.out.println("found: " + matcher.group(1) +">>>"+ matcher.group(2));
        }
```

## actual output:

```
found: 1.1>>>11.00
```

## expected output:

```
found: 1.1>>>10.00
found: 2.2>>>11.00
```

Comment: @AvinashRaj there are lot of examples in the web using while. here is one http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-regex/matcher.html#multiple-groups

Answer (score 1):

Your regex needs to be:

`String patterString = "([0-9]{1,3}\\.[0-9]{1,3}).*?CF\\s+[a-zA-Z]{1,5}([0-9]{1,10}.[0-9]{2})";`

Which yields:

```
found: 1.1>>>10.00
found: 2.2>>>11.00
```

I haven't read the docs, but guess that when iterating with `find()` it's implicitly in MULTILINE mode, so the portion of your regex `\\s.+\\s*` is greedy - replacing this with `.*?` minimizes the greed ;-)

---

Edit, sample source:

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class RegexFind {

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String text="CHANGE FEE/ADD COLLECT DATA                                   "+
                "1.1  COLOR/RED TOMATO                                         "+
                "CF   USD10.00                                                 "+
                "                                                              "+
                "2.2  COLOR/DARK BLUE PLUM                                     "+
                "CF   USD11.00                                                 "+
                "                                                              ";
        //String patterString = "([0-9]{1,3}\\.[0-9]{1,3})\\s.+\\s*CF\\s+[a-zA-Z]{1,5}([0-9]{1,10}.[0-9]{2})";
        String patterString = "([0-9]{1,3}\\.[0-9]{1,3}).*?CF\\s+[a-zA-Z]{1,5}([0-9]{1,10}.[0-9]{2})";

        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(patterString);
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);

        while (matcher.find()) {
            System.out.println("found: " + matcher.group(1) +">>>"+ matcher.group(2));
        }
    }
}
```